# Getting MissingTableException: Required table missing VERSION when starting hive metastore on mysql

Tags: mysql, hive

Hive with mysql as the metadata store stopped working:

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.exceptions.MissingTableException: 
Required table missing : "`VERSION`" in Catalog "" Schema "". DataNucleus
requires this table to perform its persistence operations. Either your 
MetaData is incorrect, or you need to enable "datanucleus.autoCreateTables"
```

Setting the autoCreateTables is not working either:

```
<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
<value>True</value>
</property>
```

So how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the $HIVE_HOME and run the initschema option on the schematool:

```
bin/schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema
```

Comment: I am trying to configure mysql with hive from a very very long time, Everytime I encounter errors I don't understand where I am going wrong ..... as you can see in this link gist.github.com/anonymous/bb86629116891e5b2d8c30b95aca9aee hive-site.xml configuration can be seen here in the link gist.github.com/anonymous/44f1c9fc214136a113067cf3b4b72794 Here is file-structure gist.github.com/anonymous/e02b3631da940dfae880252ca72107de

Comment: @KJ_kaka  Please create a separate question for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545207/unable-to-start-hive-metastore-service-or-hive-shell-after-configuring-mysql-wit?noredirect=1#comment60697449_36545207

Comment: This worked for me -- using derby instead of mysql:
bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema

Comment: But HIVE_HOME is not part of a Spark standalone right? metastore is something from Spark standalone not Hive. You hit these errors when you try to migrate from awful derby I think?

Comment: I think I got it working now (no Hive, no Derby, with postgres). Had to datanucleus.autoCreateSchemain hive-site.xml. Had to use latest postgres driver included in --packages of pyspark. Had to still create db meta data on initdb etc.

Comment: nice - getting the hive metastore up generally seems to be more difficult than expected

Comment: @Shanemeister I followed your answer, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions, it is more likely the user that you are using doesn't have permission to create privileges.

**Here is my scenario**:

I had faced the same error when I was installing Sentry service on Cloudera manager 5.7.6. i have set up sentry database as MySQL database.
It is all in GUI and 6 steps process, This issue occurred on the 5th one

What confuses you is tasks says `"Create Sentry Database Tables" 'Successfully created Sentry database tables'` but it only checks for the access to the database.

After I have change permissions it worked.