# Connect to Hive on EMR using Apache Drill Embedded

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, emr, apache-drill

I am trying to experiment on Apache Drill 1.4 in Embedded mode and trying to connect to Hive running on EMR - Drill is running on server outside EMR.

I have some basic questions that I want to get clarified and some configuration issues to be fixed.

Here is what I have so far -

Running AWS EMR cluster.
Running Drill Embedded server.

According to the documentation on configuring storage plugin for Hive, https://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/ , I am getting confused on whether or not to use Remote Metastore or Embedded Metastore. ***What is the difference?***

Next, my EMR cluster is running and here is what hive-site.xml looks like -

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9083</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description>username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
```

There are other properties defined like MySQL username and password etc. but I guess these are important here.

Which one should I use to connect to Hive? I have tried to put both these in the storage plugin but Drill doesnt take it.

Storage plugins I have tried look like this -

```
{
  "type": "hive",
  "enabled": true,
  "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9083",
    "fs.default.name": "hdfs://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/",
    "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "type": "hive",
  "enabled": true,
  "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9083",
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:derby:ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com;databaseName=data;create=true",
    "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "/user/hive/warehouse",
    "fs.default.name": "file:///",
    "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
  }
}
```

It would be of great help if you could guide me in setting this up.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing several problems -

1. VPC issue - my EMR cluster and mysql host were in different VPCs.
   Trivial.
2. Mysql connection was not happening from EMR cluster to
   mysql host - binding was strict to localhost. Removed it.
3. Now when I restarted `hive --service metastore`, I saw the error that driver name is not correct and `driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found` - so I had to download MySQL Connector driver as instructed in [Step 2 here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_hive_metastore_configure.html).
4. After MySql could connect, metastore could connect to the database : error was `mysql Database initialization failed; direct SQL is disabled`,  but
   initial tables need to be present. So the table creation had to be
   done with a command here - [Getting MissingTableException: Required table missing VERSION when starting hive on mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951747/getting-missingtableexception-required-table-missing-version-when-staring-hive)

   > Go to the
   >   $HIVE_HOME and run the initschema option on the schematool:
   >
   > `bin/schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema`

   Make sure you have cleaned up the mysql database on which you are moving this metastore. No tables or schema or tables are present that Hive needs.
5. After these, metastore was able to connect to external database. Now Hive is up and running with remote metastore.

Now I hosted Drill (embedded) in new EC2 host to connect to this metastore and it worked like a charm!

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"hive", "config": {   "type": "hive",   "enabled": true,  "configProps": {    "hive.metastore.uris":"thrift://ip-XX.XX.XX.XX.ec2.internal:9083",    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL":"jdbc:mysql://ip-XX.XX.XX.XX:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true",    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName":"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName":"root",    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword":"blah",    "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir":"/user/hive/warehouse",    "fs.default.name":"hdfs://ip-XX.XX.XX.XX.ec2.internal:8020"  }}}' http://localhost:8047/storage/hive.json
```

Answer (score 2):

*Whether or not to use Remote Metastore or Embedded Metastore?*

**Embedded Mode**: This is recommended for *testing or experimental purposes* only.In this mode, the metastore uses a Derby database, and both the database and the metastore service are embedded in the main HiveServer process. Both are started for you when you start the HiveServer process.

**Remote Mode**: The Hive metastore service runs in its own JVM process. HiveServer2, HCatalog and other processes communicate with it via the Thrift network API (configured via the hive.metastore.uris property). The metastore service communicates with the metastore database over JDBC (configured via the javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL property). This should be used for *production*.

You are using `MySQL` to store metadata for Hive. So, Drill needs `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName` & `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword` too to create connection.

Sample hive plugin (*Remote Mode*):

```
{
  "type": "hive",
  "enabled": true,
  "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris":<--->,
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL":<--->,
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName":<--->,
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName":<--->,
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword":<--->,
    "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir":<--->,
    "fs.default.name":<--->
  }
}
```

<--->  : can be taken from `hive-site.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After some further study and reading I understood the difference b/w metastores. So I am using Remote metastore. Now when I configure my HIVE plugin on the EMR master node with thrift URI `thrift://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9083` it is accepted. But it is not accepting the exact same config outside of the master node. I checked security groups they seem fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You are running drill (embedded mode) outside the cluster. Right? This is not working when you try `thrift://<slave node>:9083`?

Comment: No. I am able to add this hive plugin with localhost thrift, or even `thrift://<slave node>:9083` with public IP, but on the same node as my Hive. But it doesnt work outside of the Hive cluster.

Comment: You are running drill (embedded mode) outside the cluster. Right?

Comment: Yes. So the thing is - we have 3 : Hive, Drill (embedded) and MySQL which you need to connect to Drill. Now if I use MySQL on same cluster as Hive, and point my Drill to this MySQL, it works like a charm with Drill also on the same cluster. All 3 on same cluster. As soon as I take MySQL outside of Hive, it doesnt show my Metastore. I do it by pointing that IP in hive-site.xml. So drill also doesnt communicate. Security groups arent an issue, I checked.

Comment: Are you able to use hive properly when using MySQL outside the cluster? I mean you must have changed `hive-site.xml` for this. so ensure is hive working with changed metastore? Then use the same config for hive plugin in drill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99088/discussion-between-dev-and-rohitvk).